# MBProgressHud with storyboards

Tags: objective-c, ios6, mbprogresshud

The following code is from a sample demo.

```
HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.navigationController.view];
    [self.navigationController.view addSubview:HUD];

HUD.delegate = self;
HUD.labelText = @"Loading";

[HUD showWhileExecuting:@selector(myTask) onTarget:self withObject:nil animated:YES];
```

It uses .xibs as it views. I'm creating an application that uses storyboards. Thus there is no navigationController for the initWithView method when instantiating HUD. Is there any way to implement a HUD without using .xibs and a navigationController. I've tried passing both "self" and "self.view" but they don't work. The class that this is in is the ViewController.m class and it is a UIViewController class. So I don't see why passing self wouldn't work.

This is my code

```
HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.view];
    [self.view addSubview:HUD];
```

Again "self" is my main ViewController

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I think you want:

```
MBProgressHUD *hud = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:view];
[view addSubview:hud];    
[hud showWhileExecuting:@selector(YOUR_TASK) onTarget:YOUR_TARGET withObject:nil animated:YES];  // or NO if you don't want it to be animated
```

Alternatively, if you want to manage showing and displaying the HUD manually yourself, there's some nice convenience methods for doing that:

```
// To add HUD to a view
MBProgressHUD *hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:view animated:YES];  // or NO if you don't want it to be animated

// To set HUD text
[hud setLabelText:@"Text"];

// To remove HUD from a view (such as later in the code, after load, etc)
[MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:view animated:YES];
```

Where `view` is the view you want the HUD added/removed from.

I.e.  `self.view` on a view controller.

Comment: Your second implementation works as expected. The first one gives me an error for the @selector part. However, I tried both of these only using .xibs not storyboards. I'll try them later with that. Your first implementation is exactly like the code I have above, although mine passes the "hud" object to addSubview and not "view". Correct me if I'm wrong but I think you made a typo on that.

Comment: Yeah, it should be `[view addSubview:hud]`. Regarding the selector bit, you need to change `YOUR_TASK` (whatever your method name is) and `YOUR_TARGET` (likely `self`) to the appropriate values.

Comment: The parameters for my task and target are both my method and "self" respectively. I think the error may be that the main thread is being blocked in the method. I'll be away for a few days, but have an upvote for now.